# Add array of URLs to imageview

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, imageview, jsoup

I have the following code to get URL from HTML file using jsoup and save in array:

```
Element table2 = document.select("TABLE").get(1);
for (Element td : tr.select("td")){
                        Element img = td.select("img").first();
                        if (img == null){
                            continue;
                        }
                    String imgRelPath = img.attr("src");
                    images.add("http://hostname.com"+imgRelPath);
                    }

                }
                objImages = images.toArray();
```

The array has:

```
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/clear.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/clear.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/red.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif
http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif
```

No I need get all images from url and put into imageView one after the other. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm calling *Picasso.with* in Async Task on onPostExecute in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    ImageView estados = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.estados);
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://salesianoscarmona.com/nuevo/templates/rt_modulus_j15/images/icons/icon-crank.png").into(estados);
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

I have the import in the header:

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
```

Comment: store image in local and retrieve it using path

Comment: Use listview with custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Universal image loader for downloading images asynchronously.

```
 http://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
```

The Library itself has a sample code to download image.you may refer it..
 After downloading library  add library with your project and insert the below code at necessary place

```
String final_url="www.google.com/.....";
ImageView image;

ImageLoader  imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

imageloader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

DisplayImageOptions options; = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).considerExifParams(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();
imageloader.displayImage(final_url, image);
```

Answer (score 1):

there str several great libraries that download and set image to ImageView from url:

> http://square.github.io/picasso

or

> https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Both are great. With picasso you can easily set url to image view and it will do the job example

Picasso.with(context).load("http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif").into(imageView);

Hope this helps

Comment: I made an example like: 
`Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://www.casitreinta.com/img/noselect_menu.png").into(estados);` where `estados` is an imageView and I get this error: `Could not find method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with, referenced from method activities.monitorapp.MainActivity$Update.onPostExecute` I don't know why :(

Comment: Can you post here where are you calling from Picasso.with method. It is async task on post execute yes ? please copy some code. Have you imported Picasso properly ?

Comment: Maybe it is because of wrong context. MainActivity.this  may be wrong on that situation, maybe getbasecontext or getapplicationcontext will work for you

Comment: Y tried with  getApplicationContext and getBaseContext and the result is the same, error: ` VFY: unable to resolve static method 8119: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.with (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;` `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picass at activities.monitorapp.MainActivity$Update.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:294)`

Comment: It is hard to tell what problem is about.maybe second lib (glide) will be good for you. It is almost the same